# React HOC to conditionally render a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using antd components and I need to render components using a HOC that conditionally renders the element based on the user. This is my HOC:

```
export const withAuth = Component => props => {
  const { isAdmin } = useAppContext();
  return isAdmin ? <Component {...props} /> : null;
};
```

Basically if the user `isAdmin`, the render the component. My problem is when I use the component.

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
import {withAuth} from 'utils'
const App = () => {
  const AddAdminBtn = withAuth(Button);
  return (
    <div>
       <AddAdminBtn  />
    </div>
  )
}
```

It would be ideal if i can add props to the `<AddAdminBtn />` component like this `<AddAminBtn onChange={} type="link" title="" />`. But that doesnt work Im not sure why. What I have to do to make it work is declare a button with those props before the HOC is declared and pass that function to the hoc. Is this possible to just pass the props to the AddAdminBtn?

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way

```js
const WithAuth = ({ children }) => {
  return true ? <div>authenticathed {children}</div>: <div>unauthenticathed {children}</div>;
};

const Button = (props) => {
  return <button {...props}>button</button>;
};

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <WithAuth>
        <Button
          onClick={() => alert('hola')}
        />
      </WithAuth>
    </div>
  );
}
```